# What baking sheet material(s) are best, and at least safe, in temperatures up to 550 (°F) degrees?

Tags: equipment, temperature, heat

My oven goes up to 550 Fahrenheit degrees and it seems the sheets I've found so far are safe up to 500-450°F. Are there concerns with potential chemical releases that buyers should be familiar with if cooking at 450-550°F?

Is lining the bottom with any specific material enough to protect food from the dangers of using cookware above the suggested safe thresholds?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Fahrenheit rather than Celsius? What sort of baking sheet - aluminium? steel? coated (what sort of coating?)? silicone?

Comment: I think that's what he's asking.  What materials should he buy.

Answer (score 4):

Most good plain aluminum baking sheet will survive high temperatures like that, that's what restaurant use, they can take a beating, will last forever.

for example : https://www.bonappetit.com/story/just-buy-it-sheet-pan

Don't get a non-stick baking sheet.

If you really need something that will go to very high temperature, but might not be very practical, you could use a steep pizza "stone".

Comment: No love for steel? Every oven I ever bought comes with at least one steel roasting / baking sheet

Comment: @Luciano steel transfers heat slower. If it is a difference worth caring for, seems to be matter of opinion. It is essential in cooling electronics, I somehow doubt it would make difference in baking. But there is a difference in thermal conductivity.

Comment: @Mołot I agree - it might make a difference in lower temps but I doubt OP would be baking cookies at 550F. I thought worth mentioning because it fits the question's needs and it's very common.